How to read string parameter when using bindparam in SQLAlchemy without getting quotes?
When I pass a string as a parameter, I get quotes in the final query
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import bindparam
query = sa.text("SELECT * FROM :db").bindparams(bindparam('db', '[MyDB].[dbo].[Test]'))
print(query.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
#returns SELECT * FROM '[MyDB].[dbo].[Test]'

What I want is to get
SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Test]
I do not want to do any extra string formatting or such as I load the query text from a sql file that I run through a pre-commit hook with sqlfluff. Is this possible?
I have tried to set quotes=False in bindparam but that did nothing

bindparam is for values, not identifiers

Usually I would reflect the table into a SQLAlchemy Table object and then build my query using the object rather than trying to construct a string query.
